# Write and then read files from /tmp directory in aws lambda using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have written AWS Lambda code where I need to store an image in /tmp location of aws lambda. Below is my code:

```
String fileLocation = "loc1/loc2/";
String imageNameWithoutExt = "image1";
//creating directories first below storing the image
boolean status = new File("/tmp/"+fileLocation).mkdirs();
if(status == true){
File targetFile = File.createTempFile(imageNameWithoutExt,".jpg",new File("/tmp/"+fileLocation));
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    outStream.write(buffer);
    outStream.close();
}else{
    System.out.println("unable to create directory inside /tmp/");
}
```

And in response, it is printing the else statement:

```
unable to create directory inside /tmp/
```

What modification I need to make to write and read the files from /tmp location. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In this line of code, you are not setting the filename:

```
//write file in /tmp folder of aws Lambda
File targetFile = new File("/tmp/");
```

I think maybe you aren't showing all your code, because I don't see where the String `image1.jpg` in the error message would be coming from, but that filename needs to be added to the parameter you are passing the `File` constructor.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt reply. I have edited the code as required. Also, I'm getting the fileNotFoundException for the same line as you pointed out, but I'm providing the file name in the argument. Even then I'm getting the error.

Comment: Basically the issue is that I'm not able to write file inside /tmp folder.

Comment: I suggest doing some very basic debugging first. Try printing/logging the value of `"/tmp/"+fileNameForDirUpload` and verify it looks correct. I think you may have too many slashes in the combined String.

Comment: The printed value for *"/tmp/"+fileNameForDirUpload* is absolutely correct. Still not able to write any file inside /tmp. I have edited the code again to make the things simplify. If you can have a look and figure out the issue. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found that AWS mount tmp, and *only* allocate 1M to it. How amazon manage to get top rating is beyond me, but it seems I am surrounded by the flat earth society.

Comment: @MagicLAMP Each AWS Lambda invocation has 512MB available in `/tmp`. You are mistaken that it only has 1M.

Comment: AWS Lambda's `/tmp` storage is called 'Ephemeral Storage', and it can be increased up to 10240 MB (10 GB) in configuration > General configuration.