# How to write a file in AWS S3 bucket during AWS lambda function execution?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I've a requirement to generate file's **(.docx , .pdf)** using **docx4j and iText**. And end generated documents should be store at S3 bucket using AWS lambda function.

I've tried couple of options but none of the solution works for me. I can able to upload a local file to S3 bucket and write a normal text file to AWS S3 bucket using my java code.

However my require is, firstly I've to create a file path's for (.docx, .pdf) of the desire location i.e. S3 bucket then give a call to my code to generate the files(.docx, .pdf) and save it to S3 bucket.

NOTE: I wish to call my save method (lambda handler) which will directly save files in S3 bucket. Or either way if s3 doesn't allow to save files directly then whats the alternative aws provide to save files locally/temp so later i can  push those temp files into s3 bucket??

If any ever work on this or have an idea how to do that please share their inputs.

Comment: You need to create your file locally, do everything you need to do regarding this file and in the end upload it to bucket. I am not sure if you can open a file handler directly to your bucket. It is not a file storage, it is an object storage.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What specific problem are you currently experiencing? Are you asking how to upload a file from the Lambda function's `/tmp/` directory to an Amazon S3 bucket? Feel free to edit your question to add details.

Comment: @John Rotenstein, please check the I've adeed a NOTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. First method would be storing the file in `/tmp/` first then use the putobject API to upload to s3 specifying the bucket and keyname.

Second method is directly uploading the object to s3 using the same putobject but specifying your object.

The docs for this can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-)

A detailed example of this can be found [here](https://javatutorial.net/java-s3-example)

Comment: Let me try both the approachs. if anyone will works for me then will accept your answer. Can you please share the sample path hierarchy for /temp/ folder??

Comment: The tmp folder is simply /tmp/. You can chdir into it or save using full path eg: /tmp/abc.txt

Comment: Okay, I'll try using that temp path. let me try it once. Can we create sub directories in /temp/ folder?

Comment: I'm not sure but keep in mind that this is ephemeral storage which means it gets wiped after lambda is done executing. And the size is around 512 mb so you can't store anything big on it.

Comment: Okays, i'll keepo this in my mind. let me try it. Thanks @ninad Gaikwad

Comment: It doesn't working getting this error : Exception creating output stream: /temp/sample.docx (No such file or directory)

Comment: You can see how to write files in tmp in Java here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509229/write-and-then-read-files-from-tmp-directory-in-aws-lambda-using-java

Comment: @KhAnSaAb Use `/tmp/`, not `/temp/`. Also, please note that the contents of this directory is _NOT_ erased after execution. If the container is later re-used, then the previous files will still be in `/tmp/`. Therefore, you should erase the files before ending the Lambda function, otherwise it might run out of storage space on future executions.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein my bad, I've overlooked :( Thanks